# Make function to return custom stream

Tags: dart, dart-async

Is it possible to create a function that returns a custom stream and handles it like this?

```
user.logIn('owner', '1234')
.listen(
  success (Object user) {
    print(user);
  },
  error: (Object user, Object error) {
    print(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Why would you need/want a stream for this. Isn't this a one-time event?

Comment: yes, is it better to pass a callback param?

Comment: If it is a one-time action just return a `Future<LoginResult>` and consume it like `user.login('owner', '1234').then((loginResult) { ... }`

Comment: I was googling solutions for passing callbacks to a method, it always shows something related to stream/future.

Comment: Yeah, `Future` is for one-time results and `Stream` is for a series of events.

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/, https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/streams/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
class LoginResult {
  bool success = false;
  String username;
}

Stream<LoginResult> onLogin() async* {
  while(...) {
    yield new LoginResult()
      ..success = isSuccess
      ..userName = 'someUser';
  }
}
```

or

```
StreamController<LoginResult> onLoginController = new StreamController<LoginResult>();
// might not be necessary if you only need one listener at most
Stream<LoginResult> _onLogin = onLoginController.stream.asBroadcastStream(); 
Stream<LoginResult> get onLogin => _onLogin
...
onLoginController.add(new LoginResult()
  ..success = isSuccess
  ..userName = 'someUser');
```

Then you can use it like